# How to provide parameters to webbrowser document in windows form application?

Tags: vb.net, powerbi

I am trying to embed a Power Bi report in my application using a web browser. Everything works fine to connect to the workspace and get the token, but supplying the token to the web browser fails. I found a sample here
[Is it possible to embed power bi into desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039899/is-it-possible-to-embed-power-bi-into-desktop-application) but it seems too old.

Here is my code:

```
Dim pbiClient = GetPowerBiClientAsApp()

Dim report = pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(New Guid(wkspID), New Guid(ReportID))
report.Wait()
embedUrl = report.Result.EmbedUrl
Dim generateTokenRequestParameters = New Models.GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel:="View")
Dim embedToken = pbiClient.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(New Guid(wkspID), New Guid(ReportID), generateTokenRequestParameters)
embedToken.Wait()
tKn = embedToken.Result.Token

Dim parameters = New Object() {embedUrl, tKn, ReportID, "Report", 1, String.Empty}

AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted
WebBrowser1.Navigate(embedUrl)
```

and here is the code for `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` event:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim message = "{\""action\"":\""loadReport\"",\""accessToken\"":\""" & tKn & """\,""id\"":\""" & ReportID & """\,""\groupId\"":\""" & tenantID & """\,""\tokenType\"":""\models.TokenType.Embed\""}"
 WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("postMessage", New Object() {message, "*"})
End Sub
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Could you provide the error message or how the error looks like?

Comment: It shows no error. Just Power BI icon is flashing in the Webbrowser control and nothing happens